# Getting Encoded Vertical Line ("|") character when querying in Batch Class

Tags: soql, batch, integration

I have created a text field `SP_Login_Name__c` on user in which i am saving the sharepoint login name which i have to use for some further api requests.

Sharepoint login name is saved in the following format:
`i:0#.f|membership|test@test.onmicrosoft.com`

But when i query the same field in batch class strangely `|` character is automatically encoded to `&#124;` and following system debug is shown

```
i:0#.f&#124;membership&#124;test@test.onmicrosoft.com
```

Following is the code snippet of my batch class:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'Select Id,SP_Login_Name__c,Email,Sharepoint_Username__c,UserRole.Name,UserRoleId,Sharepoint_Group_Id__c from User where Sharepoint_Username__c!=\'\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope) {
   for(User userObj : scope){

   system.debug('###userObj.SP_Login_Name__c::'+userObj.SP_Login_Name__c); 

   String addUserEndpoint = sPCredentials[0].Sharepoint_Base_URL__c+'sites/'+sPCredentials[0].Site_Name__c+'_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById('+groupId+')/users';

   HttpRequest addUserRequest = new HttpRequest();
   addUserRequest.setEndpoint(addUserEndpoint); 
   addUserRequest.setMethod('POST'); 
   addUserRequest.setHeader('Accept','application/json; odata=verbose');
   addUserRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+sPCredentials[0].spAccessToken__c);
   addUserRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; odata=verbose');
   addUserRequest.setBody('{ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, "LoginName":"'+userObj.SP_Login_Name__c+'"}');
   system.debug('###addUserRequest::'+addUserRequest.getBody()); 
   Http addUserhttp = new Http();
   HttpResponse addUserResponse = addUserhttp.send(addUserRequest);  
   }
}
```

I want the original value stored to make a valid api request. Also i wanted to know the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Share your code as well.

Comment: I am making simple query in start method and debugging the field value in execute method.

Comment: Can you clarify whether your code actually sees `&#124;` or if this is just what the `System.debug()` shows in the log? Is the field of type Text or Rich Text?

Comment: The code when sending the request sees this `&#124;` instead of `|` vertical line due to which I am not able to send a valid request. I want the SP login name in the exact format in which i saved : `i:0#.f|membership|test@test.onmicrosoft.com` and the field is of type text.

Comment: Have you tried posting the value as received in the query and pass it on to the request, does it work? I used the same value stored in a custom field and retrieved it from developer console and printed it in log. I could see the value having a "pipe" instead of &#124. It looks like it's just printing it that way in the logs, but the values are still retrieved appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how data is stored in Salesforce Internally and How its displayed to us on the UI screen.

Internally in SF databse all other than UTF-8 chars are stored with their ASCII value.
Thus your | becomes `&#124;` .

You can check the same behaviour by using Debugging the same query in execute Anonomouys using `Database.Query('Your Query');` or normal **Select**

You cannot change the way data is stored in SF but you can change the way it is sent as a request.

```
addUserRequest.setBody('{ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, "LoginName":"'+userObj.SP_Login_Name__c.replace('&#124;','|');+'"}');
```

Comment: I have already tried to use **Replace** and **ReplaceALL** methods but salesforce is still sending `&124;` instead `|` in the request.

`addUserRequest.setBody('{ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, "LoginName":"'+userObj.SP_Login_Name__c.replaceAll('&#124;','|')+'"}');`